# How to penalize the duration of unexpected events in an elegant way?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, python, reinforcement-learning

Maybe a stupid question...em...I want to penalize the unexpected events and define the reward like this: $r_{t} =-10* (t - t_{s})$, where $t_{s}$ denotes the starting time of the event, $t - t_{s}$ is the duration of unexpected events. My question is: do I need a state to directly describe $t - t_{s}$, or I just use a flag to record $t_{s}$? In a word, how to penalize the duration of unexpected events in an elegant way?

Comment: Please add more description.  How are you handling "expected" events?  What is the broader context of your question?

Comment: The "expected" event is denoted as 0/1, and I want to define the penalty that increases with the duration of the unexpected event, e.g., $r_{t} = -10*(t-t_{s})^{2}$.